# Show/Hide Multiple DIVs based on Dropdown/Select Option

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

So I'm new to HTML/CSS/Javascript and I'm trying to create a simple form which has 5 sections which are within a seperate Div.  (So 5 Div,s)

I have a dropdown option for which the code is here

```
        <select value="Test1" name="Test1">
          <option  value="1">One</option>
          <option  value="2">Two</option>
          <option  value="3">Three</option>
          <option  value="4">Four</option>
          <option  value="5">Five</option>
        </select>
```

Depending on the options selected I want to show a different selection of Div's.

Option 1 is None Visible at all
Option 2 is Div1, Div3 and Div5
Option 3 is Div2, Div4 and Div5
Option 4 is Div1, Div3 and Div4
Option 5 is Div2 and Div4

I've been looking online at various JS and JQuery scripts to help manage this but I've managed to confuse myself.

I cannot use JQuery, it has to be Javascript.

If there is not possible way of doing this with Javascript then if a JQuery option is available I might be able to convince those that matter that it is necessary.

Thanks in advance for any help you all can give.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a javascript function like this

```js
var display = {
  1: [],
  2: [1, 3, 5],
  3: [2, 4, 5],
  4: [1, 3, 4],
  5: [2, 4]
}

function selectChanged() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("select");
  for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        document.getElementById("box" + i).classList.add("hidden");
  }
  display[sel.value].forEach(function(i) {
        document.getElementById("box" + i).classList.remove("hidden");
  });
}
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/3cuw0oks/1/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps or someone comes along with a more elegant solution. I'm still very new to this as well, but this would be my theoretical approach.

I would assign classes to the div tags. Since you can assign more than one class to an element this should work. For example:

```
<div id="Div1" class = "optionTwo optionFour hiddenDiv">content...</div>
<div id="Div2" class = "optionThree optionFive hiddenDiv">content...</div>
<div id="Div3" class = "optionTwo optionFour hiddenDiv">content...</div>
<div id="Div4" class = "optionThree optionFour optionFive hiddenDiv">content...</div>
<div id="Div5" class = "optionTwo optionThree hiddenDiv">content...</div>
```

You could then use JavaScript to determine which option is selected, then disable the hiddenDiv class from the appropriate divs, by calling it by a different class name..

```
var selectedOption = document.getElementByName("Test1")[0].value;
if (selectedOption.value == "1") {
    var element = document.getElementByClassName("optionOne");
    element.classList.remove("hiddenDiv");
}
if (selectedOption.value == "2") {
...
```

Then in the head of your HTML, you can do the following:

```
<head>
<style>
   .hiddenDiv{
      display: none;
   }
</style>
</head>
```

Just make sure that you check to see if something was selected, then the selection was changed. Because this will not add the class back to it if it's unselected. Maybe consider telling it to add the hiddenDiv class to all divs that are not affected by the currently selected option.

Comment: Thanks.  Struggling to get the hang of it but going to keep trying.  Will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

first retrieve the selected value, and select all the 5 boxes
then use a `switch`, loop throw the 5 boxes and based on the selected value 
display or hide the box

[check the code in code pen](https://codepen.io/am-77/pen/LYpgNze)

Comment: I'm struggling a little with this. Where script:
```  // Option 2 is Div1, Div3 and Div5
    case "2":
      boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
        if (index === 1 || index === 3) {
       ............
```
Can I change the 'index' to 'id' and have id on DIV's?
I assume the index for this Div. is 1
```<div class="box one">1</div>
```
Or am I wrong??
Between my <div>/</div> is an element of the form ie:
```<div class="box" id="1">
    <label> for ="Test">This is a Test</label>
    <input type="text" id="Test" name="Test">
    </div>
```
Hope that makes sense. Thanks